# Dirt Pile Remains

Tags: grass, landscaping, digging, equipment

I recently had a couple truckloads of red fill dirt dropped off, the trucks were unable to get where the dirt was needed and left it on my completely healthy lawn. Another company shuttled 90% of the dirt to where it needed to go, but now I'm left with ~500 sq ft of grass that still has ~2-3" of the dirt covering it.

1. Is the grass reasonably salvageable?
2. If yes, what is the best way to go about trying to save the grass outside of attempting to shovel bit by bit?
3. I'm fairly good at learning to use new/rented tools, so all options are on the table.
4. if it's better to hire someone to do this, who would it be (generally speaking) and what should I budget for?

Cheers,

-Chris

Comment: Pick up whatever you can with a dust pan and a heavy broom. If it's too much, best to rake/scoop it up, sell it off or give it for free....

Answer (score 1):

An iron rake, short stiff tines, to lift the grass leaves above the soil. Lots of exercise/work. It needs to be done quickly before the grass dies. I added about 2 inches of sand to St. Augustine using a rake with little or no loss. I think there is a power rake that does about the same thing. Clay in the soil will make the job more difficult.